# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Overriding Forms

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am trying to change the template for the registration form in my application so that I can add some other HTML to it.  Here is the /My/UserBundle/Resources/views/Registration/register.html.twig file:

```
{% extends "MyUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
<section class="register site-content">
    <header>
        <h1>{{ 'layout.register'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="block">
        {% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

And I have successfully overridden the layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'MyMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ site_name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for key, message in app.session.getFlashes() %}
    <div class="{{ key }}">
        {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

as well as form.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::form.html.twig' %}

{% block field_row %}
    <li class="form_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </li>
{% endblock field_row %}

{% block form_widget %}
    <ul {{ block('container_attributes') }}>
        {{ block('field_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </ul>
{% endblock form_widget %}
```

config parts:

```
# FOS User Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
      address: %admin_email%
      sender_name: %site_name%
    template:
      engine: twig
      theme: MyUserBundle::form.html.twig
```

I have cleared my cache.

Whenever I go to

http://localhost/register/

apache just hangs until it times out.

The best I can figure out, is the PHP maximum execution message says it crashes on a twig template in the cache on **line 16**.  That line is `function doGetParent(...)` The file is:

```
<?php

/* FOSUserBundle::form.html.twig */
class __TwigTemplate_9cf68a2af1db50466c556a735bcdeba0 extends Twig_Template
{
    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $env)
    {
        parent::__construct($env);

        $this->blocks = array(
            'field_row' => array($this, 'block_field_row'),
            'form_widget' => array($this, 'block_form_widget'),
        );
    }

    protected function doGetParent(array $context)
    {
        return "FOSUserBundle::form.html.twig";
    }

    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        $this->getParent($context)->display($context, array_merge($this->blocks, $blocks));
    }

    // line 3
    public function block_field_row($context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 4
        echo "    <li class=\"form_row\">
        ";
        // line 5
        echo $this->env->getExtension('form')->renderLabel($this->getContext($context, "form"));
        echo "
        ";
        // line 6
        echo $this->env->getExtension('form')->renderErrors($this->getContext($context, "form"));
        echo "
        ";
        // line 7
        echo $this->env->getExtension('form')->renderWidget($this->getContext($context, "form"));
        echo "
    </li>
";
    }

    // line 11
    public function block_form_widget($context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 12
        echo "    <ul ";
        $this->displayBlock("container_attributes", $context, $blocks);
        echo ">
        ";
        // line 13
        $this->displayBlock("field_rows", $context, $blocks);
        echo "
        ";
        // line 14
        echo $this->env->getExtension('form')->renderRest($this->getContext($context, "form"));
        echo "
    </ul>
";
    }

    public function getTemplateName()
    {
        return "FOSUserBundle::form.html.twig";
    }

    public function isTraitable()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It has **also** timed out on `\vendor\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php on line 65` Which is `public function getParent(array $context)`

So clearly there is some problem with getParent but I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the FOSUserBundle documentation:

> The easiest way to override a bundle's template is to simply place a
>   new one in your *app/Resources* folder. To override the layout template
>   located at *Resources/views/layout.html.twig* in the FOSUserBundle
>   directory, you would place you new layout template at
>   *app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig*.
>
> As you can see the pattern for overriding templates in this way is to
>   create a folder with the name of the bundle class in the *app/Resources*
>   directory. Then add your new template to this folder, preserving the
>   directory structure from the original bundle.

In my project I override FOSUserBundle's layout as they said and it's work like a charm.

So doing it at the same way you will need to create `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig`. (or the form you want to override)

**EDIT**

Ok, I just realize that you've chosen to extend the FOSUserBundle. In that case instead of `app/Resources/` you need to do it inside your bundle. But you don't need to put

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::form.html.twig' %}
```

The FOSUserBundle will detect that you are overriding the bundle and will be extended automatically.

And you also need to tell your bundle that FOSUserBundle is its parent.

```
class YourBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this since you mention removing the extends part which was my problem.

Comment: I added one more thing, that I forget to mention it.

Comment: Also, don't forget to clear your cache after editing the templates, it might be possible that's the reason your changes are not visible. (using `php app/console cache:clear`)

Comment: Cache-clearing is probably solving >80% of unexplainable Symfony errors. Just like rebooting solves >98.5% of all computer problems in general.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file:

```
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
```

to the: `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/` catalogue. Then it will overwrite the base FOS form. You can edit the copied file.

Otherwise you must override the FOS RegisterController.

Comment: That's another way to do it, sure, but I'm overriding the bundle so I can extend it in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid, just removed the `{% extends ... %}` line in form.html.twig and it worked.  I guess I don't understand enough about what is inherited in bundles. (I did want to inherit from the FOSUserBundle form.html.twig, but I don't know how to access that from a bundle which inherits from FOSUserBundle)